# Breaking Filipino laws outside of the Philippines

Tags: international, philippines, internet-scam

If some one breaks the laws of the Philippines in their own country and then visits the Philippines, what happens?

Comment: It would be helpful if you elaborated a little more. Is the person in question Filipino? What kind of law are we talking about? Criminal law?

Comment: And why is this tagged "internet-scam"?

Comment: Most jurisdictions have rules about prosecuting illegal activities outside it's own territory. But it depends on the crime committed and the nationality of the persons involved.

Comment: Welcome new user. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be enough information in your question for most (if any) users to provide an answer. But looking up [Legal Jurisdiction](https://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/jurisdiction) may help you to phrase your question better. –

Comment: Why has this been tagged for close?   While the question may not be strong now, surely there is hope it could be improved!  I think those voting to close have treated the new user rudely.

Comment: By that argument, the new user is being ride to an established community with very clear rules, by asking a question that is so vague and uncleear as to become a guessing game in what they actually want. Perhaps you need to separate the content from the person better? @Burt_Harris

Answer (score 2):

Most countries follow the same pattern: They decide what is illegal, or a crime. And they decide which crimes they prosecute. For example, the USA decided that murder is a crime, but only murders in the USA are prosecuted by the USA. (However, if you commit murder in country X, there is a good chance that the USA will extradite you to X).

So your question is a bit too general. For many crimes, if the Philippines police finds out about your crime, they might inform the country where it was committed, and extradite you when asked. There may be other crimes where you will be prosecuted in the Philippines. And of course the Philippines might decide that they don’t want criminals in their lovely islands, so they could not let you in, or remove you from the Philippines because they found out you’re a criminal.

Comment: Unless X is the UK

Comment: They could only deny entrance or deport non-citizens.

Comment: Also, most crimes of a sovereign countries with Western-style legal systems are by implication interpreted by the courts of that country to apply only to conduct in or directed at the country establishing the criminal laws in question. There are exceptions to this general rule (e.g. piracy on the high seas, and certain war crimes like genocide), but they are rare and focused.